# Would you ever need multiple D3D11 devices?

Tags: directx, directx11

I'm programming a rendering engine, and I'm considering whether on not I would need to implement the availability to call `D3D11CreateDevice()` multiple times to get multiple `ID3D11Device`'s and associated `ID3D11DeviceContext`'s.

My question is whether or not one would actually ever need to get multiple Devices in the first place? Should I bother implementing the option to do so?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you don't need it for the types of projects you design your engine for, then don't bother implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most games, a single Direct3D 11 device and single Direct3D 11 Immediate Mode Context is all you need.

You typically have multiple devices when doing DX9/DX10/DX11 interop on older versions of Windows where say Direct2D required a Direct3D 10.1 device, but you are using Direct3D 11 or if you were using DXVA which was all DirectX 9 based. See [Surface sharing between Windows graphics APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis).

Otherwise the only time you'd have multiple Direct3D 11 devices is for 'heterogenous multiadapter' scenarios which are rare. For Direct3D 11, most "multi-GPU" scenarios are virtualized into one device anyhow.

> For DirectX 12, as with most other aspects, multi-adapter requires explicit support. See [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/multi-engine).